# How to save the displayed current time in database table

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, date, time

I have this script for displaying the current date and time in my website page:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function startTime() {
var now = new Date();
var h=now.getHours();
var min=now.getMinutes();
var s=now.getSeconds();
var ampm=(now.getHours()>11)?"PM":"AM";
var d=now.getDay();
var y=now.getFullYear();
var mon=now.getMonth();

var endings=["st","nd","rd","th"];
var dayendings=[0,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,0,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,1];
var days=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var months=["January","February","March","April", "May", "June","July","August","September", "October", "Novemeber","Decemeber"];
if (h>12) {h-=12}
if (h==0) {h=12};
if (min<10) {min="0"+min}
if (s<10) {s="0"+s}

d=days[d+1];
mon=months[mon];
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=d+" "+mon+" "+[now.getDate()-6]+", "+y+" "+h+":"+min+":"+s+" "+ampm;
var tim = setTimeout("startTime()",1000);
}
</script>
```

Then, I have a textarea where the user must input his or her student number. And upon click of the submit button, the current date and time should be saved in the database. It's actually for the time in and time out of the user.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Especially if this is an official website (not just a blog or something), you want to capture server time not client computer time. Otherwise, you would be exposed to the potential for all kinds of fraud and manipulation outside of your application's control.

Answer (score 2):

Don 't trust client-side time values. There is absolutely NOT guarantee that the user's clock is accurate, or not deliberately mis-set.

If you need to log 'current time', then use something like

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (timefield) VALUES (now())
                                          ^^^^^
```

to insert a (supposedly) more trustworthy timestamp.

Comment: So, you mean my code for displaying the current date and time is wrong?

Comment: The code is not wrong - but JavaScript relies on the datetime settings of the system the browser currently runs on. So if someone accidently sets his clock to 1.1.1970 then this would be inserted in the database if you use the client datetime information. So it's better to insert the servers datetime information instead.

Comment: It is the client side time you show on the page, but if you want to log times you would want the time on the server, as this actually means something to you and the client side time (javascript) can be anything

Comment: Actually, the website that we're creating will be placed at the guard house(in the entrance), so when the student enter the school premises, he/she should enter first their student number in the website (for the time in). So, it means this website will be accessed on one computer only.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marc. Except, `NOW()` relies on the local time of your server whereas `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` will pick the unique UTC time independent location thus time offset.